# Identification: tall conifer with tamarisk-like leaves

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I am looking to identify a conifer that I found in a public park. Please see below for pictures of the leaves, bark and habit (click for full-size view).

I normally use [Pl@ntNet](https://identify.plantnet.org/) for identification, but in this case it fails: it would only suggest French tamarisk or other tamarisks based on the leaves. But those are more like shrubs, while this was a tall tree, very comparable in shape and size to the bald cypress (?) standing a few meters from it. The upward-curving leaves shown in the picture may not be entirely typical, but this small lone branch was the only one I could reach to take a photo.

Additional information:

- Location: Dresden, Germany.
- [Google street view link](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.0391895,13.7604021,3a,75y,336.16h,104.94t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipPryzokYxfN_RjmcDPGoor2Wn7ZypoDiWT7KoTB!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPryzokYxfN_RjmcDPGoor2Wn7ZypoDiWT7KoTB%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi0.3311236-ya100.6089-ro1.3409854-fo100!7i6080!8i3040), it's the one on the right.
- Leaf size: about finger length.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: @theforestecologist Updated as best as I could. I really can't put a number on the height, but it's a "tall tree", as you can see on the Google street view link I just added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like [**pond cypress**, ***Taxodium ascendens***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxodium_ascendens), (sometimes considered a variety of bald cypress: *T. distichum var. imbricatum*).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxodium_ascendens#/media/File:Taxodium_ascendens.jpg) ; Credit: [NOAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Oceanic_and_Atmospheric_Administration) (2005)</sup>

The specific epithet, *ascendens*, comes from the fact that the plant's awl-like ([sumbulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_leaf_morphology#subulate)) leaves (3-10mm long) tend to grow along erect ("ascending") green stems ; whereas bald cypress (*T. distichum*) tends to have leaves that grow in a more [distichous](http://www.botanydictionary.org/distichous.html) growth pattern.

The bark also tends to be greyer than bald cypress, but retains fibrous/shreddy bark that can become furrowed with age:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Ebben Nurseries](https://www.ebben.nl/en/treeebb/tadnutan-taxodium-distichum-nutans/)</sup>

You can [see multiple high-quality photos](https://www.carolinanature.com/trees/taas.html) on Will cook's [Carolina Nature](https://www.carolinanature.com/) site.

- For example, [this image](https://www.carolinanature.com/trees/taas1210153.jpg) showing the peely and furrowed bark.

Although native to the SE US, I found numerous records of this tree being planted in Germany (e.g., [inaturalist](https://inaturalist.lu/taxa/169570-Taxodium-ascendens)). The Dresden Garden also mentions housing *Taxodium* trees [here](https://tu-dresden.de/bg/standorte/dresden/rundgang).